# Websockets JSON to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, json, websocket, socket.io

Im trying to push data to the browser. How to get the JSON to a Javascript array? Which I can then use for selecting the first key-value or sorting the object.

Here's the code in the browser/client side:

```
socket.on('notification', function (data) {
    $.each(data.users,function(index,user) {
        usersList = user.Bob   // How to select unknown value/key? Example user[0] 
    });
    $('#koersgroot').html(usersList);
});
```

Here's the JSON format

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "Bob": 1,
            "Alice": 2,
            "Carol": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Where is the JSON? JSON is *text*; one can talk about JS objects *without* JSON (which is *text*)! And to convert between JSON and JS objects, use `JSON.parse/stringify`.. but I suspect that it (i.e. "JSON") is not related to the problem.

Comment: Is that invalid JSON or is `"users":` part of the socket message? Also, what socket library are you using?

Comment: The JSON should be valid. I ran it in JSONlint. I am using socket.io, Node.js, mysql. Yes, the JSON is part of the socket message.

Comment: What is your question, "*How to get the JSON parsed and into the `data` variable*", or "*How to select unknown value/key?*"

Answer (score 1):

JSON is representation of data. In JS it is Object data type, while JSON can be represented as string. When you send anything across WebSockets - that is string or binary.

But socket.io allows you to send Object (JSON), in fact it stringify that Object, and then parses it back into JSON on receiver side.

In order to send json, just emit object:

```
var obj = {
    users: [
        {
            "foo": 4,
            "bar": 2
        }
    ]
};
socket.emit('notification', obj);
```

And socket.io will do serialisation/deserialisation for you. So on client side:

```
socket.on('nitification', function(obj) {
    // obj is an object
    obj.users[0].foo == 4; // true
});
```

Your question is clearly consequence of lack of understanding, so you need to read a bit more, and check out examples, as the way you've asked as well as terminology is just "wrong".